# Dynamic Content Translation API Options

Tags: angularjs, translation

I'm building an AngularJS web app that I would like to offer the ability to translate user-generated dynamic content from the OP language into a handful of other languages.  One of them being Chinese.

Google Translation API is the obvious choice to accomplish this however users in China are not going to be able to use a client-side API run from Google.   I have found plenty of options for static content translation (we have that implemented already) however I have not been able to find a solution for dynamic content translation are there any options other than Google?